# Get true/false codeigniter insert function

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

every time I use insert function in my model, the return always true, here's my code

```
public function insert_text($data)
{
    return $this->db->table($this->table)->insert($data);
}
```

call code

```
if ($this->text->insert_text($data)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

even the execution failed (cause of same primary key already exists), code always return "success", how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if inserted successfuly

```
if ($this->db->insert_id()) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```